Integrating vector field in 3D space (as an inverse of gradient)
I would like to write a function (in Python) which integrates a vector field in three-dimensional grid,
saying an inverse of gradient.
I saw few examples and the logic is straightforward, but I'm getting numerically imprecise results when I validate it by reconstructing gradient back again with numpy.gradient.
How would I revise this? Is the routine itself okay?
Here's a sample code I tried:
#!/usr/bin/env python
# assume hypothetical smooth 3d vector field
# grid 51x51x51
# vector component smooth changing -2~2

import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter

## This block: generate a random smooth data of vector field in 3D space
Nx, Ny, Nz = 51, 51, 51
dx, dy, dz = 0.1, 0.1, 0.1
min_val, max_val = -2, 2
vector_field_3d = np.random.uniform(min_val, max_val, (Nx, Ny, Nz, 3))
for i in range(3):
    vector_field_3d[...,i] = gaussian_filter(vector_field_3d[...,i], sigma=3)
max_component = np.max(np.abs(vector_field_3d))
if max_component > 0:
    vector_field_3d = vector_field_3d / max_component * (max_val - min_val) / 2
vector_field_table = vector_field_3d.reshape(-1,3)

np.savetxt('smoothtest_vector_field_table.dat',vector_field_table,fmt='%15.8f')


## Try integration, and validate the result with reconstructing gradient again
def reverse_gradient_integrate_tripleloop(table3d_vector_field,grid_spacing):
    dx, dy, dz = grid_spacing
    table3d_integ = np.zeros(table3d_vector_field.shape[:3])
    #dxintegral = np.cumsum(table3d_vector_field[:,:,:,0], axis=0)*dx
    #dyintegral = np.cumsum(table3d_vector_field[:,:,:,1], axis=1)*dy
    #dzintegral = np.cumsum(table3d_vector_field[:,:,:,2], axis=2)*dz
    nx, ny, nz, nq = table3d_vector_field.shape
    for i in range(1,nx):
        table3d_integ[i,0,0] = dx*(table3d_vector_field[i-1,0,0,0]) + table3d_integ[i-1,0,0]
        for j in range(1,ny):
            table3d_integ[i,j,0] = dy*(table3d_vector_field[i,j-1,0,1]) + table3d_integ[i,j-1,0]
            for k in range(1,nz):
                table3d_integ[i,j,k] = dz*(table3d_vector_field[i,j,k-1,2]) + table3d_integ[i,j,k-1]
    return table3d_integ

def reverse_gradient_integrate_diagonal(table3d_vector_field,grid_spacing):
    dx, dy, dz = grid_spacing
    fx, fy, fz = table3d_vector_field[:,:,:,0], table3d_vector_field[:,:,:,1], table3d_vector_field[:,:,:,2]
    nx, ny, nz, nq = table3d_vector_field.shape
    table3d_integ = np.zeros(table3d_vector_field.shape[:3])
    # diagonal consideration: for every grid, take all 3 f_xdx,f_ydy,f_zdz values adjacent by [i-1,j-1,k-1] cell
    # this way uses full information.
    # first, complete (1) edges (2) surfaces (2d diagonal from edge values) then (3) inner values
    # (1) 3 edges
    table3d_integ[:,0,0] = np.cumsum( fx[:,0,0] )*dx
    table3d_integ[0,:,0] = np.cumsum( fy[0,:,0] )*dy
    table3d_integ[0,0,:] = np.cumsum( fz[0,0,:] )*dz
    # (2) surfaces
    for i in range(1,nx):
        for j in range(1,ny):
            table3d_integ[i,j,0] = dx*fx[i-1,j-1,0] + dy*fy[i-1,j-1,0] + table3d_integ[i-1,j-1,0]
    for i in range(1,nx):
        for k in range(1,nz):
            table3d_integ[i,0,k] = dx*fx[i-1,0,k-1] + dz*fz[i-1,0,k-1] + table3d_integ[i-1,0,k-1]
    for j in range(1,ny):
        for k in range(1,nz):
            table3d_integ[0,j,k] = dy*fy[0,j-1,k-1] + dz*fz[0,j-1,k-1] + table3d_integ[0,j-1,k-1]
    # (3) full inner elements
    for i in range(1,nx):
        for j in range(1,ny):
            for k in range(1,nz):
                table3d_integ[i,j,k] = dx*fx[i-1,j-1,k-1] + dy*fy[i-1,j-1,k-1] + dz*fz[i-1,j-1,k-1] + table3d_integ[i-1,j-1,k-1]
    return table3d_integ

def reverse_gradient_integrate_doublediagonal(table3d_vector_field,grid_spacing):
    table3d_integ_forward = reverse_gradient_integrate_diagonal(table3d_vector_field,grid_spacing)
    table3d_vector_field_rev = table3d_vector_field[::-1,::-1,::-1,:]
    table3d_vector_field_revm = -1.0*table3d_vector_field_rev
    table3d_integ_backward_rev = reverse_gradient_integrate_diagonal(table3d_vector_field_revm,grid_spacing)
    table3d_integ_backward = table3d_integ_backward_rev[::-1,::-1,::-1]
    table3d_integ = (table3d_integ_forward + table3d_integ_backward) / 2.0
    return table3d_integ

nx, ny, nz = 51, 51, 51
dx1, dy1, dz1 = 0.1, 0.1, 0.1

force_q3_columns = np.loadtxt('smoothtest_vector_field_table.dat')

force_q3 = force_q3_columns.reshape(nx,ny,nz,3)

#table1_energy3d = reverse_gradient_integrate_tripleloop(force_q3,(dx1,dy1,dz1))
table1_energy3d = reverse_gradient_integrate_doublediagonal(force_q3,(dx1,dy1,dz1))
table1_energy3d -= table1_energy3d[-1,-1,-1]
table1_energy3d *= -1.0

## Appendix: gradient calculation again for validation
gf3d_x, gf3d_y, gf3d_z = np.gradient(table1_energy3d,dx1,dy1,dz1,edge_order=1)
gf3d_x *= -1.0
gf3d_y *= -1.0
gf3d_z *= -1.0
recon_force_q3 = np.stack((gf3d_x, gf3d_y, gf3d_z), axis=-1)  # (nx, ny, nz, 3) array
gradient_recon_error = recon_force_q3 - force_q3
fmag_recon_error = np.linalg.norm(gradient_recon_error,axis=-1)
print('Mean latent gradient force reconstruction error check: ',np.mean(fmag_recon_error))

print('reconstructed force q3 grid data shape:', recon_force_q3.shape)
recon_force_table = recon_force_q3.reshape(-1,3)
np.savetxt('reconsmoothtest_vector_field_table.dat',recon_force_table,fmt='%15.8f')


My output message tells that:
Mean latent gradient force reconstruction error check:  1.4047385997086408
Which is a substantially large mean error norm considering the magnitudes of the original sample.
As I attached on the code block, I first tried the simplest forward integration (reverse_gradient_integrate_tripleloop) and got larger numerical error,
so switched to the function of diagonally computing the integrals considering all increments of three axes fxdx,fydy,fzdz from (i-1,j-1,k-1) cell.
Then, considering that np.gradient counts both forward and backward cell's data to calculate slope, I tried averaging the two results from forward integration and backward integration.
reverse_gradient_integrate_doublediagonal somewhat reduced the error, but still it's large.
Is this problem intrinsically non-unique? or would you point out that the functions I'm using is invalid?
I would appreciate any kind of advice. Thanks!

This paper (with Matlab code here) does what you're trying to do but in 2D, maybe you could generalise one of the methods there to the 3D problem rather than inventing your own. Though, you should note that even in 2D with real data none of the methods are completely robust and have errors due to boundary condition violations etc...

Thank you so much @Nin17 ! I would like to try that for general success of this task.
Also, I found (with a few note and pencil practice) my trial function reverse_gradient_integrate_diagonal is logically inconsistent with commonly used gradient computations. It's wrong because it takes dx dy dz increments from diagonally adjacent [i+-1,j+-1,k+-1] cells, when gradients are taken from linearly adjacent [i+-1,j,k], [i,j+-1,k], [i,j,k+-1] cells to present the derivatives along x,y,z axes.
